# Why am I getting this error? Error: Unable to locate a 'Type' by the name: 'User:#Default'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, odata, breeze, datajs

I am trying to adapt the OdataBreezeJSSample into my project.  The metadata is getting called and populated, but my query:

`var people = breeze.EntityQuery
                .from("Users")
                .using(manager)
                .select('Email')
                .execute()
            .then(function() {
                })
            .catch(function(err) {
                var isEmpty = manager.metadataStore.isEmpty();
            });`

is failing with error message:

Error: Unable to locate a 'Type' by the name: 'User:#Default'. Be sure to execute a query or call fetchMetadata first.

Inspecting the metadataStore shows in my project as:

[image: Inspection of metadata (Not Working)]

Inspection of the sample that works, the metadata looks different:

[image: Inspection of metadata (Working)]

As far as I can tell my setup code matches the sample.  Also I am using the same versions of the libraries.  The query never fires off, the only call that gets made is to GET the $metadata.

I have tried calling fetchMetadata(), but it just creates a duplicate call to /$metadata.

What could be causing this error message?

UPDATE:

Here is the EDMX.  I have confirmed that there is only 1 schema in the working sample.  I can't figure out where this extra schema is getting generated from. All of the code to generate the EDM matches the sample.

`<xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="1.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx">
  <edmx:DataServices m:DataServiceVersion="3.0" m:MaxDataServiceVersion="3.0" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
    <Schema Namespace="SCATowel.Models" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm">
      <EntityType Name="User">
        <Key>
          <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
        </Key>
        <Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="Name" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="Login" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="Email" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="IsAppAdmin" Type="Edm.Boolean" Nullable="false" />
        <NavigationProperty Name="Sites" Relationship="SCATowel.Models.SCATowel_Models_User_Sites_SCATowel_Models_Site_SitesPartner" ToRole="Sites" FromRole="SitesPartner" />
        <NavigationProperty Name="Settings" Relationship="SCATowel.Models.SCATowel_Models_User_Settings_SCATowel_Models_Setting_SettingsPartner" ToRole="Settings" FromRole="SettingsPartner" />
      </EntityType>
      <EntityType Name="Setting">
        <Key>
          <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
        </Key>
        <Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="SiteListLocation" Type="Edm.String" />
        <NavigationProperty Name="User" Relationship="SCATowel.Models.SCATowel_Models_Setting_User_SCATowel_Models_User_UserPartner" ToRole="User" FromRole="UserPartner" />
      </EntityType>
      <EntityType Name="Site">
        <Key>
          <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
        </Key>
        <Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="Title" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="Url" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="IsSiteAdmin" Type="Edm.Boolean" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="IsSiteOwner" Type="Edm.Boolean" Nullable="false" />
        <NavigationProperty Name="User" Relationship="SCATowel.Models.SCATowel_Models_Site_User_SCATowel_Models_User_UserPartner" ToRole="User" FromRole="UserPartner" />
      </EntityType>
      <Association Name="SCATowel_Models_User_Sites_SCATowel_Models_Site_SitesPartner">
        <End Type="SCATowel.Models.Site" Role="Sites" Multiplicity="*" />
        <End Type="SCATowel.Models.User" Role="SitesPartner" Multiplicity="0..1" />
      </Association>
      <Association Name="SCATowel_Models_User_Settings_SCATowel_Models_Setting_SettingsPartner">
        <End Type="SCATowel.Models.Setting" Role="Settings" Multiplicity="*" />
        <End Type="SCATowel.Models.User" Role="SettingsPartner" Multiplicity="0..1" />
      </Association>
      <Association Name="SCATowel_Models_Setting_User_SCATowel_Models_User_UserPartner">
        <End Type="SCATowel.Models.User" Role="User" Multiplicity="0..1" />
        <End Type="SCATowel.Models.Setting" Role="UserPartner" Multiplicity="0..1" />
      </Association>
      <Association Name="SCATowel_Models_Site_User_SCATowel_Models_User_UserPartner">
        <End Type="SCATowel.Models.User" Role="User" Multiplicity="0..1" />
        <End Type="SCATowel.Models.Site" Role="UserPartner" Multiplicity="0..1" />
      </Association>
    </Schema>
    <Schema Namespace="Default" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm">
      <EntityContainer Name="Container" m:IsDefaultEntityContainer="true">
        <EntitySet Name="Users" EntityType="SCATowel.Models.User" />
        <EntitySet Name="Settings" EntityType="SCATowel.Models.Setting" />
        <EntitySet Name="Sites" EntityType="SCATowel.Models.Site" />
        <AssociationSet Name="SCATowel_Models_User_Sites_SCATowel_Models_Site_SitesPartnerSet" Association="SCATowel.Models.SCATowel_Models_User_Sites_SCATowel_Models_Site_SitesPartner">
          <End Role="SitesPartner" EntitySet="Users" />
          <End Role="Sites" EntitySet="Sites" />
        </AssociationSet>
        <AssociationSet Name="SCATowel_Models_User_Settings_SCATowel_Models_Setting_SettingsPartnerSet" Association="SCATowel.Models.SCATowel_Models_User_Settings_SCATowel_Models_Setting_SettingsPartner">
          <End Role="SettingsPartner" EntitySet="Users" />
          <End Role="Settings" EntitySet="Settings" />
        </AssociationSet>
        <AssociationSet Name="SCATowel_Models_Setting_User_SCATowel_Models_User_UserPartnerSet" Association="SCATowel.Models.SCATowel_Models_Setting_User_SCATowel_Models_User_UserPartner">
          <End Role="UserPartner" EntitySet="Settings" />
          <End Role="User" EntitySet="Users" />
        </AssociationSet>
        <AssociationSet Name="SCATowel_Models_Site_User_SCATowel_Models_User_UserPartnerSet" Association="SCATowel.Models.SCATowel_Models_Site_User_SCATowel_Models_User_UserPartner">
          <End Role="UserPartner" EntitySet="Sites" />
          <End Role="User" EntitySet="Users" />
        </AssociationSet>
      </EntityContainer>
    </Schema>
  </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>`

Comment: What namespace is User in, on the server?

Comment: SCATowel.Models, I added the schema above with some more information.

Answer (score 2):

@Adel asked what I was going to ask. See [**Brian Noyes discussion of the issue**](http://briannoyes.net/2013/02/16/consuming-an-asp-net-web-api-odata-service-with-breeze/). Sadly, the `ODataConventionModelBuilder` is not faithful to the EDMX.

It gets worse. The `ODataConventionModelBuilder` does not preserve the essential foreign key information which means you really can't use it for Breeze apps. The OData team acknowledges the deficiency. When will they fix it? No one knows.

> Why are you using Web API OData? Why not straight Web API ... which I find to be both easier and superior almost every time. The ONLY reason I would use Web API OData is if I had to expose my web api to clients that I don't control ... clients that are also prepared to consume OData.

Let's assume you have such a good reason.

Did you notice the part in the [**Web API OData Sample**](http://www.breezejs.com/samples/breeze-web-api-odata#BuildEDM) where we advise against using the `ODataConventionModelBuilder` and direct you to the `EdmBuilder`. Are you doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Did you make the `Users` Collections exposed in `WebApiConfig.cs` in `App_Start` Folder?

```
public static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
{
     ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
     builder.EntitySet<User>("Users");
     builder.Namespace = "SCATowel.Models"; 
     return builder.GetEdmModel();
}
```

Source:
[Open Data (OData)](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/odata)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I think it's just because metadata from EF is not good for breeze.

Like it's explain here http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/odata-server you just have to install EdmBuilder with nuget like so :

```
Install-Package Breeze.EdmBuilder
```

And then add this to your **WebApiConfig.cs** :

```
config.Routes.MapODataRoute(
    routeName: "odata",
    routePrefix: "odata",
    model: EdmBuilder.GetEdm<MyDbContext>(),
    batchHandler: new DefaultODataBatchHandler(GlobalConfiguration.DefaultServer)
);
```

And it should work.